# Should I quit my job as a software engineer and join the coding bootcamp?

Tags: new-job, quitting

I have majored in computer science when I was in college, and got my first job right after graduating. I am working for a large corporate company, and have been working there for almost two and a half years.

I never really got a chance to take on a coding project, even though I got hired as a software engineer. Because of the fall in the market share, a lot of the projects have been dismissed, people have been getting laid-off, and most of the projects here have been sent over the headquarter overseas (I'm working for subsidiary in the U.S.).

So, either I'm doing a lot of test engineering for products being made from the headquarter, or most of the time I have nothing to do at work. I have been job hunting starting from last year, and got interviews, but I have been failing go past the interviews because my coding skills have been declining since college. I had been working on side projects using Android Java and Ruby on Rails, been studying for technical interviews through online resources, but it's not as easy as I thought as I get really unmotivated sometimes.

When I heard about the coding bootcamp, I finally found my hope to really expertise myself in coding, and leave my current company. The only thing I'm concerned is whether it is a good idea for people who are already software engineers (but inactive at work) to quit their current jobs, join the coding bootcamp, and get another software engineer job in a different company.

Any thoughts? Money is not a concern for me, all I want is to be able to obtain the expertise myself in coding and technical interviews and get a real programming job.

Comment: It is **much** easier to get hired for a software job when you are already employed. Learn to code alongside your job, and you'll do much better than if you quit to join a bootcamp.

Comment: We cannot answer this question for you - only you know your financial situation and whether it is feasible to quit your job.  A few years ago my wife got into an accident as she was turning left when one car stopped for her and waived for her to turn.  She was turning and didn't notice that a second car in the other lane was driving the speed limit and crashed right into her.  The first car was only waiving based on him being at a stand still and not really looking at the lane next to him to help my wife.  My point is don't act on an answer by people you don't know...else it could be bad.

Comment: Coding bootcamps are a scam, I'd recommend free online videos (which are a great free source) or a better option is to use Pluralsight. Speaking from a fulltime SE, don't waste your money on a bootcamp when there are much cheaper options

Answer (score 4):

> Should I quit my job as a software engineer and join the coding
>   bootcamp?

This is almost **never** a good idea, as you never know how long it might take to get the next job.  I would suggest you find a bootcamp, *which by the way I think is great idea*, that offers after hours or weekend classes.

Part of being a developer is keeping your skills up to date and marketable.  This will be on you no matter what so you may as well get used to after hours training while employed.

Comment: Alternatively, you could take vacation time to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best motivators for me is money, so if i were you I would try to find a developer entry position to start coding for a living, so I could have full time practice and make a living out of it. Plus you can still learn whatever you want in your personal time.
So my answer is only quit your job if are going to work in another place doing what you like. Just quitting and stop working is a step back in your career.